# Latex: tableof contents only for a section

Tags: latex, tableofcontents

As it is a looong appendix, I would like to add a "tableofSECTION" on the first page of the section. However, tableofcontents always lists everything and the level is - as far as I can see - only defined as a "to" variable, but not "from".

What I would like to see:

```
SECTION TITLE
x.1 subsection    122
x.2 subsection    144
etc.
```

And dump the rest of the ToC.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want to take a look on the minitoc package.

http://texblog.wordpress.com/2008/09/15/create-small-tocslofslots-using-minitoc/